# How to show just one function from a stored plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization, sorting, eigenvalues

**Q:**
Is there a general way to remove particular functions from a previously stored call to a plot function?

*Here is a specific example:*

```
plot1 = Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 2}];
plot2 = plot1;
plot3 = plot1;
plot2[[1, 1, 1, 3]] = {};
plot3[[1, 1, 1, 4]] = {};
{plot1, plot2, plot3}
```

[image: Plot dissection]

But I'd like to do it on other plot functions, like Plot3D.

*Here's an attempt at that:*

```
plot1 = Plot3D[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}];
plot2 = plot1;
plot3 = plot1;
plot2[[1, 2, 1, 1]] = {};
plot3[[1, 2, 1, 2]] = {};
{plot1, plot2, plot3}
```

[image: Plot3D dissection]

You can see that I can get rid of the most of the plots of `x` and `x^2` individually again, but now the mesh remains. Perhaps I could poke around inside the Plot3D object some more and get rid of those, but you may also notice that the relevant indices for `Plot` and `Plot3D` are different. Rather than doing microsurgery on my plots every time I want to do this, I was hoping there was a general method to do this cleanly.

*Ideally, the solution should also work on something like:*

```
mat={{x^2+y^2-1,0},{0,-x^2-y^2+1}};
plot1=Plot3D[Sort[Eigenvalues[mat]],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
```

(but with a way bigger matrix!)

Here's why I care: I have a reasonably nasty matrix (216x216) which is a function of two variables. Only numerical methods have any hope of getting its eigenvalues, and it's sufficiently nasty that `Eigenvalues` does not return the eigenvalues in any particular order. That means that I have to call `Sort` on the results of `Eigenvalues` before plotting in order to get anything that doesn't look like it's been run through the wood-chipper.

But that means that if I just want to plot one band, I first have to get the numerical eigenvalues corresponding to that x and y for ALL bands.

Well, I really want to plot all bands, just not all on the same graph. Now, if I plot each band separately, it's going to find all those eigenvalues every single time. That's a huge waste of time, since in principle, Mathematica has all the info it needs on the first call.

So I would like to make one call to `Plot3D` on the full spectrum of eigenvalues which I would store like in the examples above, and then make copies of that which have all but one or a few bands removed from the plot.

Thanks for getting into the nitty gritty with me!

Comment: unlike polygons mesh lines are note separated into groups. So it is difficult to eliminate the right set of lines. To get just the surfaces (without the lines) you can do `plot2 =Normal@ plot1;plot3 =Normal@ plot1;plot2[[1,1, 2]] = plot2[[1,1, 1,2]] = {};plot3[[1,1,2]] = plot3[[1,1,1,1]] = {};`

Comment: why not move `Sort@Eigenvalues@mat` outside `Plot3D`, that is, use, `ev = Sort[Eigenvalues[mat]];plots = Plot3D[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] & /@ ev`? or `plots = Plot3D[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> #2] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{ev, {Red, Blue}}]`?

Comment: .. or `MapThread[ Plot3D[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> #2] &, {ev, {Red, 
   Blue}}]`?

Comment: if it  is ok to have just the surfaces you can also do : `{plot2,plot3} =Graphics3D/@Cases[Normal[plot1], {__,_GraphicsGroup}, All]`

Comment: @kglr, as OP explained, it is only possible to compute `ev` numerically, so simply moving `Sort@Eigenvalues@mat` outside of `Plot3D` is hardly possible. One thing to try is to precompute `Eigenvalues` in `Table`-like way (on a mesh of `x` and `y` with some small enough steps) and then to `ListPlot3D` these `Sorted` bands. Or even make then some `Interpolation`.

Comment: @kglr, thanks for the extra info on the guts of `Plot3D`. I do in fact move the `Sort@Eigenvalues@mat` outside of the plot in my own code, but as @Alx points out, that serves only for notational convenience. After asking this question yesterday, I went the route of `ListPlot3D`. It looks at least as good as `Plot3D`, and it is MUCH faster.

Answer (score 6):

```
plot1 = Plot3D[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, ImageSize -> Medium];
```

We get the surfaces by extracting `GraphicsGroup`s:

```
surfaces = Graphics3D[#, Options@plot1]&/@Cases[Normal[plot1], {__, _GraphicsGroup}, All];
```

Getting correct set of lines for each surface is challenging. The following seems to work (not sure how robust it is in general):

```
lines = Cases[Normal[plot1], _Line, All];
partition = Partition[lines[[1 + Length @ surfaces ;;]], 15];
meshlines = Graphics3D /@ MapIndexed[Flatten[Prepend[#, lines[[#2]]]] &, 
    Transpose[Partition[partition, Length @ surfaces]]];

Row[Prepend[MapThread[Show, {surfaces, meshlines}], plot1]]
```

[image]

**Note:** the magic number 15 above is the default number of mesh lines in x and y directions. The lines are organized as follows: if there a k surfaces, the first k lines are the boundary lines for the k surfaces. The next 15 k lines are mesh lines in x direction and the last 15 k lines are mesh lines in y direction. In each group, the first 15 lines belong to the first surface, the second 15 lines belong to the second surface etc.

For

```
plot1 = Plot3D[{x, x^2, 2+Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, ImageSize -> 300];
```

we get

[image]

For

```
mat = {{x^2 + y^2 - 1, 0}, {0, -x^2 - y^2 + 1}};
plot1 = Plot3D[Evaluate[Eigenvalues[mat]],  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium];
```

we get

[image]

If we use `Sort[Eigenvalues[mat]]` in the previous example we get a single surface and the approach breaks down. Using `Evaluate[{RankedMin[#,1],RankedMin[#,2]}&[Eigenvalues[mat]]]` instead of `Sort[Eigenvalues[mat]]`

```
plot1 = Plot3D[Evaluate[{RankedMin[#,1],RankedMin[#,2]}&[Eigenvalues[mat]]],  
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium];
```

we do get multiple surfaces but  we need to change the magic number 15 to 31 to get

[image]

So for a more robust approach:

```
ClearAll[separatePlots]
separatePlots = Module[{opts = Options[#], 
     gc = Cases[#, GraphicsComplex[c_, ___] :> c, All][[1]], 
     gcsurfaces = Cases[#, {___, _GraphicsGroup}, All], 
     gclines = Cases[#, _Line, All], pts, surfaceMeshAssoc},
    pts = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Cases[#, Polygon[x_, ___] :> x, All][[1]]]] & /@ 
      gcsurfaces;
    surfaceMeshAssoc = GroupBy[Function[x, 
     {First @ MaximalBy[Range[Length@gcsurfaces], 
       Length[Intersection[pts[[#]], x[[1]]]] &], x}] /@ gclines, First -> Last];
    Prepend[Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[gc,
      {surfaceMeshAssoc[#], gcsurfaces[[#]]}], opts] & /@ Range[Length@ gc surfaces], #]]&;
```

***Examples:***

```
Row @ separatePlots @ Plot3D[{x, x^2, 2 + Sqrt[x]},  {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

```
Row @ separatePlots @ Plot3D[Evaluate[{RankedMin[#, 1], RankedMin[#, 2]} &[
     Eigenvalues[mat]]],  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},  
    PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

```
mat2 = {{-1 + x^2 + y^2, 0, x y }, {0, 1 - x^2 - y^2 , x + y}, {x y, 
    x + y, 1 - x^2 - y }} ;
Row @ separatePlots @ Plot3D[
  Evaluate[{RankedMin[#, 1], RankedMin[#, 2], RankedMin[#, 3]} &[Eigenvalues[mat2]]],  
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},   PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

**Reap/Sow**

An alternative approach is to use `Reap`/`Sow` to get the evaluations inside `Plot3D` and use `ListPlot3D` on the reaped evaluations:

***Examples:***

```
{plot, evaluations} =  Reap[ Plot3D[(Sow[Thread[{x, y, #}]]; #) &@
           {x, x^2}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
         PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium]];

plots = MapThread[ListPlot3D[#, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotStyle -> #2] &,
      {Transpose[evaluations[[1]]], {Red, Blue}}];
Row[Prepend[plots, plot]]
```

[image]

```
mat = {{x^2 + y^2 - 1, 0}, {0, -x^2 - y^2 + 1}};
{plot, evaluations} =  Reap[
   Plot3D[(Sow[Thread[{x, y, #}]]; #) & @ Sort[Eigenvalues[mat]], 
    {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium]];

plots = MapThread[ListPlot3D[#, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotStyle -> #2] &,
      {Transpose[evaluations[[1]]], {Red, Blue}}];
Row[Prepend[plots, plot]]
```

[image]

For

```
mat2 = {{-1 + x^2 + y^2, 0, x y }, {0, 1 - x^2 - y^2 ,x+y},{x y, x+y,1 - x^2 - y }} ;
```

(changing `{Red, Blue}` to `{Red, Blue, Green}`) we get

[image]

Comment: +1 for `Rip / Sow`

Comment: Thank you @Alx.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it might come in handy regardless. Check out the resource function `CheckboxLegended`, which makes it easy to create plots with controls for turning data on and off:

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CheckboxLegended

The central idea behind `CheckboxLegended` is to style your plot with a `Dynamic` opacity so that you can toggle the opacity between 0 and 1. The following code snippet illustrates the idea:

```
opacity = 1;
Plot[Style[Sin[x], Opacity[Dynamic[opacity]]], {x, 0, 5}]
Slider[Dynamic[opacity], {0, 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to trying out this new toy!